# how can I mount localhost for GlusterFs?

Tags: apache, localhost, glusterfs

I have two nodes for `GlusterFS` and mount on `/var/www/`, everything works fine about `GlusterFS`, but when I run firefox for `Localhost` this error appears:

> Forbidden. You don't have permission to access / on this server.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check file permissions for `/var/www/` and subfolders. Make sure that the webserver is able to read those files.